# Минимизация функции 3-х переменных в R

Tags: r

Всем здравствуйте. 
Имеется код

```
calls <- read.table(file = "Call_options.txt", row.names = 1);
row.names(calls) <- strptime(row.names(calls), format = "%d-%m-%Y");
dates <- as.POSIXlt(row.names(calls));
strikes <- c(6325, 6350, 6351, 6375, 6400, 6425, 6450, 6475, 6500, 6525, 6550, 6575, 6600, 6625, 6650, 6675, 6700, 6725, 6750, 6775, 6800, 6825, 6850, 6875, 6900, 6925, 6950, 6975, 7000, 7025, 7050, 7075, 7100, 7125, 7150, 7200, 7250, 7300, 7350, 7400, 7500, 7600, 7800, 8000, 8400, 8800, 9600);

time_now <- dates[1];
time_end <- dates[length(dates)];

f <- function(a) {
sum <- 0;
for (i in 1:length(strikes)) {
moneyness <- strikes[i] / calls[as.character(time_now), 2 * i];
fact_premuim <- calls[as.character(time_now), 2 * i - 1];
if (!is.na(moneyness) && !is.nan(moneyness) && !is.na(fact_premuim)) {
  sigma <- exp(a[1] + a[2] * moneyness + a[3] * moneyness * moneyness);
  d1 <- log(calls[as.character(time_now), 2 * i] / strikes[i]);
  d1 <- d1 + sigma * sigma * (as.numeric(time_end - time_now)) / 2;
  d1 <- d1 / (sigma * sqrt(as.numeric(time_end - time_now)));
  d2 <- d1 - sigma * sqrt(as.numeric(time_end - time_now));
  premium <- calls[as.character(time_now), 2 * i] * pnorm(d1) - strikes[i] * pnorm(d2);
  sum <- sum + (premium - fact_premuim)^2;
  }
}
return (sum);
}
```

Параметр 'a' в функции f 3-мерный. Математически это задача минимизация квадратичного функционала по 3 переменным. Для более легкого понимания напишу аналог:

```
f <- function(a) {
   sum <- 0;
   for (i in 1:10)
     sum <- sum + ( a[1] + a[2] - 2 * a[3] + i^2 )^2;
   return (sum);
}
```

Минимизирую я таким образом:

```
optim(c(1,1,1), f);
```

Но в ответ получаю ту же точку (1,1,1). В общем какую точку я начальную введу, она и будет в ответе. Где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Ваша вторая функция может быть переписана следующим образом: `f <- function(a, n) sum((a[1] + a[2] - 2 * a[3] + seq_len(n)^2)^2)`. Вызывая `optim(c(1, 1, 1), f, n = 10)$par`, мы получаем `-3.831078 -7.831753 13.420716`. Если ваши результаты отличны, то представьте пример кода, который бы в точности воспроизводил проблему.

Comment: Перепись второй функции на результат не повлиял. К тому же разные начальные значения приводят к разным результатам оптимизации. Тут уж совсем странно. Что думаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f <- function(a, n) sum((a[1] + a[2] - 2 * a[3] + seq_len(n)^2)^2)  
require(rgenoud)  
opt <- genoud(f, nvars = 3, starting.values = c(1,1,1), 
          Domains = matrix(c(-10,10,-10,10,-10,10), ncol=2, byrow = T),
          data.type.int = T, n=20) 
'wait.generations' limit reached.
No significant improvement in 10 generations.
Solution Fitness Value: 5.292260e+05
Parameters at the Solution:

 X[ 1] :    -9.000000e+00
 X[ 2] :    -1.000000e+01
 X[ 3] :    1.000000e+01

Solution Found Generation 1
Number of Generations Run 12

Sat Mar 19 15:15:17 2016
Total run time : 0 hours 0 minutes and 1 seconds  
> opt$par
[1]  -9 -10  10
```

Ну гдето так..

Comment: Вы думаете, что лучше прибегать к генетической оптимизации?

Comment: Конечно. Функция genoud найдет глобальный оптимум (или близкое к нему значение) фитнес функции независимо от того непрерывна ли ф-я, дифференцируема ли. Кроме того не накладывает ограничений на параметры, позволяет рекурсивные вызовы самой себя и т.д. Поизучайте, пригодится.